# RC4 Find Key from plain text and encrypted data

Tags: encryption

Assuming a have some plain text and the corresponding encrypted data, is it possible to find the key in faster than brute force time? If so, how do I do this?

To clarify: I have plaintext p and encrypted data d. They can be strings or a byte array, or whatever you prefer. I just want to know if it is possible to obtain the key from this data.

Comment: How much is *some* plain text? As much as you want? More than 4GB? How many different message streams? One big one or as many small ones as you want? There is some key biasing that might help.

Comment: A relatively small amount of plaintext and encrypted data. Let's say about 20 bytes. I know I can xor the data to get the keystream, but I'm not sure how to get the key from there.

Comment: In general, you can't recover the key from the keystream. But if the same RC4 key is reused you can use the same keystream to recover the cleartext. A proper implementation will avoid this by generating different RC4 keys for different sessions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That explains why I was having such trouble finding a way to determine the key.

Answer (score 1):

See [Attacks on the RC4 stream cipher](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aUP7hH0C5x9UJ%3acage.ugent.be/~klein/RC4/RC4-en.ps+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). RC4 provides effective security when used carefully and properly, but it's not that hard to make a mistake either.